# Quick search of the face descriptors in the db

Tags: database, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I want to implement something like face recognition application using neural networks. So I found [this incredible article](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78#.z0z23o1wa).

When we put the face image in the OpenFace network we get 128 measurements which we can use to compare faces.

**But here we get the main question: how we can quickly find the same face in the database with the closest 128 values?**

If we will use SVM(as it is written in the article) we should to retrain the classifier every time when we put the new face in the db, but it's inexpedient.

So I would to know what is the best approach for this issue? How services like Facebook compare these descriptors in the millisecond?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a face and want to search a database of faces for the closest match(es) there's actually only two steps (assuming you've already gotten the 128 OpenFace measurements - which I'll call the OpenFaceRep):

1. For each face in your database, subtract its OpenFaceRep from the OpenFaceRep of your seed photo. We'll call this `diff`
2. Get the dot product of that `diff` with itself. If you're in Python, it would look something like `np.dot(diff,diff)`, and we'll call that the `similarity`.

The face with lowest `similarity` will be the best match. Note that your accuracy will vary quite a bit depending on the quality of your photos, lighting, etc. OpenFace has achieved an [accuracy of about 92%](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/models-and-accuracies/#performance) on the LFW benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I also think it is the most accurate method, but if we want to check each face in the our db with the query face it will take a long time: we need to subtract 128 values n-times, where n - count of the rows in the db table. I think that it is exist some more quick method for this. Or maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: It seems like you understood me correctly. What I described would be quite fast (since it's just subtraction and multiplication) and could be implemented in parallel. I've actually been wondering a lot about how to scale this - as far as I know, there is not much open source research on the topic. My guess is that Facebook is able to "cheat" in a way by only comparing faces in your photos to your friends. So at most, they're doing a couple of thousand comparisons. You may also want to check out [Amazon Recognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/), which could simplify things for you.

Comment: Of course, I'm completely forgot about this Facebook hack. Ok, thanks! I will try to test method described by you and let you know about results. But I also want to clarify: I think I can also use KD-tree for this purpose, what are you think about it?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's in line with one approach I've thought of. Divide your data into k clusters (I was thinking t-SNE), then only compare your face to the faces in the cluster to which it would be assigned. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late replies. I have a lot of exams in these weeks. I thought I need to use 128 dimensions in the KD-tree, but you suggest to reduce dimensionality to 3 dimensions and then use KD-tree with this data, correct? Also I want to know: whether PostgreSQL can use KD-tree in the same way that I need? I read [this article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-types.html) about it, but I'm still not sure if I should to use it for my purpose.

Comment: Still not sure what you meant in your previous comment, can you clarify it?

Comment: Now I start to look in the side of t-SNE, but [have some trivial(I think) issues with this algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430233/adding-new-points-to-the-t-sne-model), please check it. Thanks!