# Adding new points to the t-SNE model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I try to use t-SNE algorithm in the scikit-learn:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
model = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
model.fit_transform(X)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.00017599,  0.00003993], #1
       [ 0.00009891,  0.00021913], 
       [ 0.00018554, -0.00009357],
       [ 0.00009528, -0.00001407]]) #2
```

After that I try to add some points with the coordinates exactly like in the first array `X` to the existing model:

```
Y = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
model.fit_transform(Y)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.00017882,  0.00004002], #1
       [ 0.00009546,  0.00022409]]) #2
```

But coords in the second array not equal to the first and last coords from the first array.

I understand that this is the right behaviour, but **how can I add new coords to the `model` and get the same coords in the output array for the same coords in the input array?**

Also I still need to get closest points even after appending new points.

Comment: I think it's because the algorithm can transforms the whole model, so, you can't modify existing model by adding new points, the algorithms adapts to the *whole* data. And probably there is a math condition.

Comment: Your new points should change the existing transformations and it's normal that the second case gives you different transformatoons.

Comment: @sergzach yes, as I already wrote I understand that this is the normal behavior. But can I somehow change(of course without full reestimating) the algorithm(not in the scikit) for my purpose?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but from looking at the (source code)[https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py#L689), you'll want to run `_fit` with the `skip_num_points` option. This is basically a modification of the `fit_transform` function.

Comment: @Tchotchke many thanks for your support! I have checked this function with some test indices but it doesn't give any difference([some github users say the same](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5361#issuecomment-147552086)), also I note that I can't store in the RAM all my points, so t-SNE will not work. Maybe I can try some other dimensionality reduction method which can be applied for my task([my previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272915/quick-search-of-the-face-descriptors-in-the-db?noredirect=1&lq=1))? What are you think?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the author of t-SNE from here: https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/

> Once I have a t-SNE map, how can I embed incoming test points in that map?
>
> t-SNE learns a non-parametric mapping, which means that it does not learn an explicit function that maps data from the input space to the map. Therefore, it is not possible to embed test points in an existing map (although you could re-run t-SNE on the full dataset). A potential approach to deal with this would be to train a multivariate regressor to predict the map location from the input data. Alternatively, you could also make such a regressor minimize the t-SNE loss directly, which is what I did in [this paper](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/AISTATS_2009.pdf).

Also, [this answer on stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/398806/79829) contains ideas and a link to

> a very nice and very fast recent Python implementation of t-SNE https://github.com/pavlin-policar/openTSNE that allows embedding of new points out of the box

and a link to https://github.com/berenslab/rna-seq-tsne/.